# Sizes of Hamming balls on the discrete torus

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coding-theory

Consider the discrete torus $\mathbb Z^2_k $, with $k$ even, i.e. the graph with vertex set $\{0,1,\dots, k-1\} \times \{0,1,\dots, k-1\}$ and edges between any pair of vertices which differ in exactly one coordinate by $1$ (modulo $k$).

Denote by $d(0,v)$ the *graph distance* on $\mathbb Z^2_k $ between the origin, that is the vertex of coordinate $(0,0)$ and the vertex $v$. Let $B_r$ be *the Hamming ball of radius* $r$ centered at the orgin, defined as
$$
B_r:=\{ v \in \mathbb Z^2_k ~:~d(0,v) \leq r\},
$$
and denote by $b(r):=|B_r|$ its cardinality.

Is there a way to characterize/describe/compute the sequence $b(1),\dots,b(k)$? If $r<k/2$, then the toroidal boundary has no effect on the Hamming balls and thus $b(r)=1+4 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^r i$. But what can be said in the case $r \geq k/2$?

Comment: Why don't you just translate the origin by $(k/2, k/2)$? When the ball is larger than $k/2$, you will get a small, shrinking square/diamond in the middle; after translation you will get the same effect, but these will be triangles in the corners.

Comment: You can put the origin where you want, or equivalently center the Hamming balls wherever you prefer. How does this help in answering my question, though?

Comment: Am I mistaken or you are talking about the discrete version of [city metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)? When the origin is at the center, no shortest path to any vertex goes over the edge, so you can work with a simple discrete plane, rather than torus.

Comment: It is indeed Manhattan distance on the discrete torus $\mathbb Z^2_k$. I agree that the maximum value for such a distance is equal to $k$ (or in other words that $B_k \equiv \mathbb Z^2_k$) and that if the origin is at the center there exists a shortest path that does not go over the periodic boundaries of the discrete torus. However, for any value of the radius $r$ between $k/2$ and $k$ the Hamming balls do wrap around and self-touch, so looking at the planar case is not enough, I believe.

Comment: Take $r = 0.75 k$ and imagine you paint all the elements in your ball blue. What is the shape of the uncolored part?

Comment: This is a special case of what is also known as the Lee-distance. Lee distance uses the same idea but in $\Bbb{Z}_k^n$ instead of $n=2$ as here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Let $m$ be the special element $m=(k/2,k/2)$. I denote by $B(0;r)$ (resp. $B(m,r)$) the ball with radius $r$ centered at $0$ (resp. $m$), so your $B(r)$ is my $B(0;r)$.

- Show that for all the vectors $v$ you have $$d(0,v)+d(m,v)=k.$$
- Show that for all $r, 0\le r\le k$, $v\in B(0;r)$ if and only if $v\notin B(m;k-1-r).$
- Show that for all $r, 0\le r\le k$, $v\in B(0,r)$ if and only if $v+m\in B(m,r)$.
- Show that for all $r, 0\le r\le k$, $b(r)+b(k-1-r)=k^2$.